# Android doesn't retrieve the right access token for Azure AD authentication

Tags: java, android, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am developing an Android application that uses MSAL for Android. A user authenticates himself via this library to get an access token, this token is then used for authorization with the Sharepoint Api.

I have an Azure AD registration setup which we use to provide the token. We already have a working version of the app where the user can authenticate himself via a refresh token. This refersh token is retrieved via the web browser using the standard microsoft authentication flow (getting an authentication code, calling the api with the code and saving the refresh token).

I now want to do the same authentication but with MSAL instead of the user having to get a refresh token manualy. I already have a working configuration and can log in with a microsoft account, but when I use the token to call the Sharepoint api we get this error:`

`{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}`

The token is retrieved via this code:

```
private ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication mSingleAccountApp;
private final static String[] SCOPES = {"Sites.FullControl.All"};

PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(getApplicationContext(),
                R.raw.auth_config_single_account, new IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreated(ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
                        Log.d(Misc.LOGTAG, "OnCreated Called, set mSingleAccountApp");
                        mSingleAccountApp = application;
                        loadAccount();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                        displayError(exception);
                    }
                });


 btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mSingleAccountApp == null) {
                    Log.d(Misc.LOGTAG, "mSingleAccountApp == null");
                    return;
                }
                mSingleAccountApp.signIn(UploadActivity.this, null, SCOPES, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
                btnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

          btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mSingleAccountApp == null) {
                    Log.d(Misc.LOGTAG, "mSingleAccountApp == null");
                    btnLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnLogout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }
                mSingleAccountApp.signOut(getSignOutCallback());
            }
        });

private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallback() {
        return new AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                /* Successfully got a token, use it to call a protected resource - MSGraph */
                accessToken = authenticationResult.getAuthorizationHeader();
                Log.i("token", accessToken);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                /* Failed to acquireToken */
                Log.d(Misc.LOGTAG, "Authentication failed: " + exception.toString());
                displayError(exception);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                /* User canceled the authentication */
                Log.d(Misc.LOGTAG, "User cancelled login.");
            }
        };
    }

    private ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.SignOutCallback getSignOutCallback() {
        return new ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.SignOutCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSignOut() {
                btnLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull MsalException exception) {
                displayError(exception);
            }
        };
    }
```

After retrieving the access token, we use it to make the sharepoint api call:

```
public interface SharePointService {

    @Headers({"Accept: application/json; odata=verbose"})
    @POST("/sites/{siteName}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{url}')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='{file}')")
    Call<ResponseBody> CreateFile(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Path("siteName") String siteName, @Path("url") String url, @Path("file") String file, @Body RequestBody fileContent);
}
```

The authorization header contains the token with the 'Bearer ' prefix.

The Azure AD app registration has the right scope configured + a platform configuration for the android app. Most developers find the problem with a scope that isn't set right, but I don't see any problem with out Azure configuration.
[image: snippet of the Azure API authorization page]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created app registration with following permissions / scopes ,

[image]

Gave Scope as https://.sharepoint.com/.default and tried the scenario in postman.

[image]

Received the error: Invalid Audience , even after giving correct scopes and api permissions with admin consent granted.

**To call the sites using graph:**

[image]

***`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites`***

Here as graph api is called, we need to have ***`https://graph.microsoft.com /.default`*** as scope, which gives the output upon API call.
For that call token endpoint with https://graph.microsoft.com /.default as scope and then call sharepoint api with the access token with graph scope.

[image]

**Output:** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites

[image]

**But if the site endpoint is called without using grah api endpoint, then scope must be ***`https://<tenantdomain>.sharepoint.com/.default`***  must be given**

And the proper query to call sharepoint site api is

***`https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/sites`***

[image]

My auth code was:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=782xxxb3a1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=query&scope=https://tenantdoamin.sharepoint.com/.default
```

the code , i got as below ,

[image]

Token endpoint: I used the code that I got .

**With proper scope and correct api call , I could get the call to be made successful to sharepoint api.**

Comment: After following the steps here I got to the root of the problem. It had to do with the defined scopes, using ''Sites.FullControl.All" as a login scope is not enough. You have to prefix with your sharepoint url, something like https://*****.sharepoint.com/Sites.FullControl.All . After changing this everything worked as expected